# Does Isomorphic SmartClient have a callback that fires when a user selects a pick list record on a form text item?

Tags: javascript, smartclient

I am developing a web application using Isomorphic SmartClient. I am searching for a callback fired when the user selects a pick list record from a DynamicForm TextItem pick list, but I am unable to find one. Does a callback for this event exist in SmartClient? If not, is there a good way to tell when the user has selected a pick list record?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about ComboBoxItem probably(and even if it is SelectItem it is the same) and they extends TextItem, which extends FormItem. FormItem and it's subclasses do have changed method - http://www.smartclient.com/docs/10.0/a/b/c/go.html#method..FormItem.changed
But this one will fire, after change is done, in case you need to handle control on the time of change - use change method (and you can even stop the change by returning false) - http://www.smartclient.com/docs/10.0/a/b/c/go.html#method..FormItem.change

Good luck